# Excel: Find matches from Col A and Col B which have highest corresponding Col C value, return Col D corresponding name

Tags: excel, indexing, max

I have a table with four columns. Column A has thousands of part numbers, all of which are unique. Column B also contains a list of part numbers, many of which appear multiple times, and all appearing somewhere in Column A. Column C contains values for the quantity of each part corresponding with Column B. Column D contains a vendor name relating to the specific quantity of that specific part from Columns B and C.

I need a command that can take a value from column A, compare it to all the values of Column B, and return the corresponding vendor name from Column D when the values from A and B match. The catch is that if the value appears multiple times in Column B, I only want the vendor name returned of the part with the **highest** Column C quantity.

Here's what it looks like:

```
            Col A               Col B        Col C          Col D

            1234;               1234;         6;            Mikey's

            1455;               1234;         12;           Jerry's

            1767;               1542;         78;           Bill's

            1542;               1767;         45;           Ted's

                                1455;         59;           Joe's
```

I would like to return in a new column E:

```
             Jerry's

             Joe's

             Ted's

             Bill's
```

PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE help me. I have toiled through days of research and scouring the internet to find an answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you sort the list descending by column C, then you can directly run a `INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2,B:B,0))` (because the first match will be the highest

Comment: That worked wonderfully. I appreciate your help Dirk!